# attach one unrelated row to MySQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, union

I have a massive SQL query that returns a very large table of results.

How can I attach one entry to that result, with a simple different query, to skip extra access to the database?

e.g. for columns `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` say I get a result of 3 rows, I wish to add a row for only when `e = 0`, and bring its `f` value, in this example it's `9`, ignoring all the other many conditions on the other columns, and leave the rest of the row `NULL`, the result should be something like that:

```
|a|b|c|d|e|f|
|1|2|3|4|5|6|
|6|5|4|3|2|1|
|1|3|4|2|5|6|
|N|N|N|N|0|9|
```

Comment: Do you want to add this row in MYSQL or can you add it in whatever language you are using to consume this result?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you, I updated the tags. I am using python.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just need to add it to the result of the query, I will use that row later.

Comment: *I wish to add a row for only when e = 0, and bring its f value, in this example it's 9*: where does the `9` comes from? Please eplain the logic.

Comment: Of course, if you showed us the complete query, some SQL guru here could probably come up with a really nice answer to this

Answer (score 1):

This would probably make more sense to do that in the application that consumes the data.

In MySQL, you could use `union all` to add the required record to your resultset (which you seem to be aware of, since you tag your question with `union`).

So something like:

```
select -- your massive query here
union all
select null, null, null, null, 0, null
```

`union all` will generate the record regardless of what the massive query returns. If there is a change that the massive query might also generate the same record, and you want to avoid duplicates, you can use `union`(but that means more work for your RDMBS, that will need to search both `union`ed resultsets for duplicates).

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I updated the question. I need total of 2 values.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a UNION after your existing query

```
<your query>
UNION
SELECT 'N','N','N','N',0,'N'
```

Or if you really mean NULL

```
<your query>
UNION
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,NULL
```

So after clarification:

```
<your query>
UNION
SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,e,f 
FROM <table> t
WHERE t.e = 0
<may require other clauses in the where>
```

Comment: Maybe OP only wants row if there is a row in data where e = 0..

Comment: @P.Salmon ah maybe so :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, I wasn't clear. I updated the question. I need total of 2 values.